# UniVerse database | catalog command line parsing error

Tags: database, u2, unidata, universe, multivalue-database

I am new to Universe-database trying to publish my SUBROUTINE compiled at universe-database version (11.1 and 10.1.5) successfully at windows and Linux.

Publishing SUBROUTINE command

**CATALOG filename HELLO**

I am using universe 11.1 at windows and able to publish my SUBROUTINE successfully.

on other hand i am using universe 10.1.5 at Linux and found following error.

**Abnormal termination of UniVerse. Fault type is 11.  Layer type is Unknown. Segmentation fault**

what could be the possible reason.

please, suggest the appropriate solution.

Comment: Sounds like you do not have the database set up correctly.

Comment: You might not have enough RAM on the Linux machine.

Comment: Is it just this SUBROUTINE, or does it do it for any program? If it is any program, you have a misconfiguration in either your UniVerse config, or in Linux (such as permissions).

Comment: Does 'CATALOG filename HELLO DIRECT' work?

Comment: While i just type command CATALOG and press enter. Then, i get message  "CATALOG command line parsing error."

Comment: 'CATALOG filename HELLO DIRECT' do not worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means a physical error in the database. Same like if the files are corrupted.

You could try the command `uvfixfile`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't push the object code around from a Windows system to a Linux system.  Move the source code over, recompile and then catalog it on the Linux system.